# Is locking required when swapping variable reference in multithreaded application?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I have an application where I want multiple threads to read a list. I want to update the list with new data periodically. When the list is updated, I figure I can create a new list and replace it with the old one. Example:

```
private List<string> _list = new List<string>();
private void UpdateList()
{
    var newList = new List<string>(QueryList(...));
    _list = newList;
}

private void ThreadRun()
{
    foreach (var item in _list)
    {
        // process item...
    }
}
```

In the `UpdateList` method, a new list is created and the `_list` reference is swapped with the new list. From my thinking, any existing thread will still hold the reference to the old list (which is OK for me), any new thread will pick up the new list. Eventually, all threads will end and the old list will be eventually garbage collected. Is there any locking required in this code, or is there anything I need to take care of to ensure safe multi-threaded access?

Comment: What does `QueryList` do? Are elements of `_list` ever modified by a different thread (added or removed)?

Comment: dQueryList just returns a collection of strings. I purposely showed that a new list is created, to show that the list is never moified.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be sure neither staleness nor optimisations hurt you, use `Interlocked.Exchange()` to update the field. Then you'll have an appropriate memory barrier on the write, without the expense of having `volatile` on every read.

Comment: I haven't considered using Interlocked.Exchange(). Are you saying this is faster than using volatile?

Comment: Could you elaborate this a bit? As far as I know, all `Interlocked` methods generate (full) memory barriers. In other words, they are slower, but safer than `volatile`.

Comment: @Groo They are slower than a write to volatile, but since the reads outnumber the writes in the scenario given having a write by Interlocked and plain reads would be faster overall than having every read and write be to volatile.

Answer (score 4):

You're making instances of the list immutable and it is only mutable state that causes problems.

Your code is fine, but you should consider marking `_list` as `volatile`. This would mean that all reads get the latest version and the compiler / jitter / cpu won't optimise away any reads.

Alternatively, you could put a `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` just before you assign the new list to make sure that all writes to the new list are committed before you publish it, but it's not a problem on x86 architecture.

Comment: If it's volatile, then what's the memory barrier for?

Comment: I don't think _list needs to be volatile in the case, as it is read once at the start of ThreadRun(), if it was read in a loop and the new value was wanted, then it would need to be volatile to stop it being cashed in a register by the compiler.

Comment: x86 has a strong memory model that makes life easier. Windows also supports Itanium and Atom processors that have weaker memory models. On top of this, you have the .NET memory model, both the ECMA spec and the .NET 2 implementation. This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163715.aspx) is useful.

Answer (score 3):

Assignment is atomic, your code is fine. You may wish to consider marking `_list` as volatile though to ensure that any threads that request the variable get the most up to date version:

```
private volatile List<string> _list = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using .NET 4 or+ you can use the new new thread safe collections...

```
BlockingCollection<string> list  = new BlockingCollection<string>();
```

The BlockingCollection class has thread-safe methods for adding and removing members, rather like the Producer Consumer design pattern.

Threads can add and other threads can remove list members with no programming overhead.

Additionally, it allows you to do things like this...

```
    foreach (string i in list)
    {
        list.Take();
        list.Add(i + 200);
    }
```

This code removes and adds to a collection while its enumerator is working, something that could never be done in c# prior to .NET 4.  There is no additional need to declare it volatile.

```
    foreach (string i in list)
    {
        new Task(() =>list.Take()).Start();
        new Task(() =>list.Add(i + 200)).Start();
    }
```

In this snippet, N*2 threads are started that all operate on the same list...

The different behaviour implicit in using Concurrnt Collections may obviate the need for you to have two lists.

Comment: That has completely different behaviour though.

Comment: Completely different behaviour.

Comment: Answer amended.  No need to repeat yourself a 3rd time with no explanation  :)

Comment: I was thinking it would be faster to just create new lists, rather than synchronizing access to the list. That means more work for the garbage collector though.

Comment: I honestly just couldn't see how this would answer the question. If the end-goal is though one where some threads are adding and some removing, then the non-blocking synchronisation used internal to BlockingCollection with its default use of a ConcurrentQueue would indeed be better. Also, if you don't want the reading threads to wait in the case of their being no content one could just use a ConcurrentQueue directly.

Comment: Step 1: create a copy of the list; Step 2: overwrite the original list.  And Step 1.5 (between steps 1 and 2 and occuring in a different thread): an item is added to the original list.  That's a race condition.

Answer (score 3):

You need to read up on the .net memory model, as in general the order of rights are not defined on a processor, so  a new value of _list may be written to shared memory, while part of a new created object pointed to by _list is still in a processors write queue.

Reordering of rights are a pain to think about, so I would tent to insert  a [Thread.MemoryBarrier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.memorybarrier.aspx)();   like this.

```
private void UpdateList() 
{     
    var newList = new List<string>(QueryList(...));   
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();  
    _list = newList; 
}
```

See the [Threading in C# web page by Joseph Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx) for more details

However I think on most "normal" processors your code will work as writen.